# How to store the number of nodes expanded by Minimax

Tags: java, memory, nodes, minimax

I'm creating a Java program to play the Connect Four game using the Minimax and Alpha-Beta Pruning algorithms. I'm adapting the following pseudocode for the Minimax algortihm:

[Minimax pseudocode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DE5bX.png)

The thing is, at the end of the game, one of the values I have to print is the number of nodes expanded during the execution of the algorithm, to give and idea of the memory usage and to compare it with the number of nodes expanded by Alpha-Beta Pruning. However, I don't really know what is the best way of keeping track of this value. A colleague of mine kept it as a field in the class that represented the grid. His solution involves keeping track of a certain **maxDepth** variable declared inside the Minimax class:

```
static Values decision(Tabuleiro tab,int depth){
    Instant start = Instant.now();
    int maxDepth = 1,children = 1;
    Values v = new Values(-1*infinity,1);

    for(Tabuleiro a: LibTabuleiro.makeDescendants(tab, 2)){
        Values tmp = min(a,depth-1); maxDepth = Math.max(maxDepth,tmp.getY());
        v = Values.max(v, new Values(tmp.getX(),a.getLast())); children++;
    }

    tab.setSize(maxDepth+children); /*setSize sets the field in the grid class
    which contains the maximum number of nodes stored in memory simultaneously*/
    Instant end = Instant.now();
    return new Values((int)Duration.between(start,end).toMillis(),v.getY());
}
```

which in turn involves the use of this Values class:

```
public class Values {
int value;
int depth;

Values(int v,int d){
    value = v;
    depth = d;
}

int getX(){return value;}
int getY(){return depth;}

boolean lowerThan(Values other){return this.value<=other.value;}
boolean greaterThan(Values other){return this.value>=other.value;}

static Values max(Values a,Values b){
    if(a.value >= b.value) return a;
    else return b;
}

static Values min(Values a,Values b){
    if(a.value <= b.value) return a;
    else return b;
}
}
```

but I was wondering if there is a more straightforward way of doing this as, to be perfectly honest, I don't understand everything his code does and I shouldn't copy it either.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is `makeDescendants` recursive? That would be more useful to show instead of the Values class. Otherwise, assuming `makeDescendants` is recursive, just returning the `children` value should be sufficient. Adding the depth to it is incorrect.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for your reply. `makeDescendants`is not recursive. It returns a LinkedList of `Tabuleiro`(grids) which result from dropping a chip in each of the the 7 columns of a Connect Four grid, if the move is possible.

Comment: Ok, I am missing where your recursive call is to alternate between players. `decision` takes a depth parameter but does not call itself.